# Cannot pass object with interface type 'NSString' by value to variadic function; expected type from format string was 'id'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I wrote the following code in X-Code,

```
NSString  *myString = @"testString";
NSLog(@"*myString = %@", *myString);
```

and I got the following error,

> Cannot pass object with interface type 'NSString' by value to variadic function; expected type from format string was 'id'

can someone tell me what does it mean? What does "*myString" stand for?
As we know, if we write the code like below, there is no error,

```
char testchar = 'f';
char *char1 = &testchar;
NSLog(@"*char1 = %c",*char1);
```

Why NSString cannot write like this case?

@Avi,Thanks for your explanation, originally, what I want to ask is I saw the below declaration and definition:

```
NSString const *BNRNextItemValuePrefsKey1 = @"NextItemValue";
```

From my understanding BNRNextItemValuePrefsKey1 a pointer to a constant @"NextItemValue"
but when I do the following, there is no error, 
    BNRNextItemValuePrefsKey1 = @"jijijij";
why this happen,can you explain it?

Comment: Get rid of the `*` on the `NSLog` line.

Comment: I know that, but I want to know what does the "*myString" mean.

Comment: If you knew to get rid of the `*` then why are you posting a question about an error when mistakenly using the `*`?

Comment: Pls see my update in the question, I feel confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `*myString` is dereferencing the pointer `myString`.  It tells the compiler to pass the value contained at the memory location pointed to by the pointer, instead of passing the value of the pointer itself.  The reason that example gives you an error is because Objective-C does not allow passing of objects by value.  You are only allowed to pass pointers to objects.  The reference to `id` in the error message is pointing out that the `%@` format string is used to print objects.  Exactly what gets printed for any object depends on the implementation of `- description` for that object's type.

Your second example with the pointer to a `char` works because Objective-C has no issues with passing the value of a `char`.

**question edit**

In that statement the `const` attribute refers to the value being pointed to, not the value of the pointer.  In terms of implementation, it doesn't really mean much, as that string will not be changeable anyway.  I believe it allows for compiler optimizations.